# In Scopy's oscilloscope view, how do you reset the view after you draw a box with cursors?

Tags: oscilloscope

In Scopy (by Analog Devices Inc.), when the Oscilloscope mode is active, how do you reset the view after you draw a box with cursors? I don't see a button.